# Baffled over the value of a variable passed to a java function

Tags: java, sorting

I have a function which implements selection sort. The sorting works fine. However, somehow, the head which was passed in gets changed from the end of the function body to the function call. Don't look at the whole code, just look at the function call and the last line of the function.

```
import java.util.*;


public class Sorting<E>
{

public static void sort( ListNode<String> head )
{
    if ( head == null )
        return;

    int eff_size;
    int size = 0;

    ListNode<String> last = null;

    for ( ListNode<String> node = head; node != null; node = node.getNext() )
    {
        size++;
    }

    System.out.println( "size is " + size );

    for ( eff_size = size; eff_size > 1; eff_size-- )
    {
        ListNode<String> biggest = head;
        ListNode<String> node = head;
        ListNode<String> biggestprevious = null;

        for ( int i = 0; i < eff_size-1; i++ )
        {
            if ( node.getNext() == null )
                break;

            if ( node.getNext().getValue().compareTo( biggest.getValue() ) > 0 )
            {
                biggestprevious = node;
                biggest = node.getNext();

            }
            node=node.getNext();
        }

        if (biggest.getNext()!=null){
            if (biggestprevious!=null && biggest.getNext()!=last){
                biggestprevious.setNext( biggest.getNext() );
            }
            if (head == biggest){
                head = biggest.getNext();
        }

            biggest.setNext( last );
            System.out.println(" node is " + node.getValue());

            if (node != biggest){
                node.setNext(biggest);
            }
        }

        last = biggest;

    }

     System.out.println("head at function end is - " + head.getValue());
}

public static <E> ListNode<E> buildList( E[] values )
{
    ListNode<E> head = null;
    ListNode<E> tail = null;
    for ( E value : values ) // for each value to insert
    {
        ListNode<E> node = new ListNode<E>( value, null );
        if ( head == null )
        {
            head = node;
        }
        else
        {
            tail.setNext( node );
        }
        tail = node; // update tail
    }

    return head;
}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner kbd = new Scanner( System.in );
    boolean done = false;

    Sorting<String> ex = new Sorting<String>();

    do
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println( "   (D) sort( ListNode<String> head )" );
        System.out.println( "   (Q) Quit" );
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print( "Enter a choice:  " );
        String response = kbd.nextLine();

        if ( response.length() > 0 )
        {
            System.out.println();

            switch ( response.charAt( 0 ) )
            {

                case 'D':
                case 'd':
                    ListNode<String> headD = buildList( new String[] {
                       "B", "F", "K", "Q", "Ant", "Aardvark",
                       "apple" } );


                    System.out.println("head before function call is - " + headD.getValue());
                    sort( headD );
                    System.out.println("head after function call is - " + headD.getValue());

                    break;

                default:
                    if ( response.toLowerCase().charAt( 0 ) == 'q' )
                    {
                        done = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print( "Invalid Choice" );
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    } while ( !done );
    System.out.println( "Goodbye!" );
}
```

}

The output I get:

head at function end is - Aardvark

head before function call is - B

head after function call is - B

I know the list is sorted, because at the end of the function I did a:

```
System.out.println("---------------------------------");
for ( ListNode<String> node = head; node != null; node = node.getNext() )
{

    System.out.println(node.getValue());
}
```

and I get:

```
Aardvark
Ant
B
F
K
Q
apple
```

However somehow the head is messed up!

I don't understand how head is remaining as 'B'. I am a beginner to Java (high school) and I from what I understand, head gets passed in by reference so it should get changed inside the function and the changes should get reflected.
Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a reference to a single ListNode - the one that contains "B". This is not to be confused with the object representing the entire list - something your list processing library doesn't seem to provide (as opposed to Java's own List implementations).

In your sort program you need to keep track of the node containing the minimum value and return that (guessing: `return head;`) , replacing the headD in your main program:

```
headD = sort( headD );
```

Note that changing head in sort doesn't help: head is a reference, and that is passed by value, so any change isn't visible at the point of invocation.

Comment: Yes that works..Thanks so much! Now if only they allowed us to change the function signature. Ridiculously designed assignment.

Comment: In that case I'd have a field `ListNode<E> sortedHead` in class Sorting, make sort a proper method that sets sortedHead after sorting and add a getter ListNode<E> getSortedHead()`. (Keeping everything static is, of course, technically possible, but not very OO.) - The alternative is to swap the values of the ListNode elements without juggling with any links.

Comment: Thanks! Managed to do it by changing values using setValue(). Also, gave you an upvote now that my rep is above 15 :)